# Serverside debug Django "Not Acceptable"

Tags: django, http-status-code-406

When calling an URL on my Django API it returns:

`[04/Sep/2021 08:14:47] WARNING [django.request:224] Not Acceptable: /api/calendar/test.ics`

Calling the same URL from PostMan (or curl) returns a simple iCal file so the URL is valid and returning.

What I found was that the cause is the "Accept" headers sent by the client.
The problem is that the request never actually hits my view so I cannot inspect request.META for the value of the received accept header.

How can I discover, serverside, what headers were sent and what their values are?

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what is going on. But, If you want to inspect the headers, you can define add the `dispatch` function to your class based view, something like:

```
class MyView(APIView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.debug("{}".format(request.META))

        if request.method == 'GET':
            return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            return self.post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request):

    def post(self, request):
```

The strange thing is, now with the `dispatch` function added to the view, the request is somehow accepted.